# Some Inequality based on sin and cos functions

Tags: calculus, inequality

Can we show that
$$8r -16r^2\sin^2\dfrac{\theta}{2}-16R^2\cos^2\dfrac{\theta}{2}\leq 0$$
for all real values $r>0$ and $R$.

Or, we need some restrictions for $r$ and $R$?

Comment: Take $r=R$ then the whole thing is $8r(1-2r)$ which is positive for $r\in (0,1/2)$.

Comment: @BenjaminWang That's right! Can we prove by some restrictions on $r$ and $R$?

Comment: You definitely need restrictions. For example if $\theta=0$ you can choose $R$ small enough so it does not hold for a given $r>0$.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

This is not an answer, just an observation. Replacing $r$ with $y$ and $\theta$ with $x$. We get the graph above.

Some fiddling around gives us that $0.5 \leq r \leq 2R^2$. This is just a rough outline though, as I haven't smoothed out anything for the parameters (I just took the two constant extrema)

Answer (score 0):

We can rewrite the expression as

$$\begin{eqnarray} 8r - 16r^2 \sin^2 \frac{\theta}{2} - 16 R^2 \cos^2 \frac{\theta}{2} & = & 8r - 16r^2 \sin^2 \frac{\theta}{2} - 16 R^2 (1 - \sin^2 \frac{\theta}{2}) \\
& = & 8r - 16 R^2 + 16 \sin^2 \frac{\theta}{2} (R^2 - r^2)
\end{eqnarray}$$

Since $0 \leq \sin^2 \frac{\theta}{2} \leq 1$, this expression will range between $8r - 16R^2$ and $8r - 16 r^2$. Thus, for it to always be strictly less than 0, we need it to be less than zero at both endpoints.

Setting $8r - 16r^2 < 0$ gives $0 < r < \frac{1}{2}$, while $8r - 16R^2 < 0$ gives $R^2 > \frac{r}{2}$, which in turn requires $|R| > \frac{1}{2}$.